# Bubble style chat in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

I want to create a bubble style chat application like WhatsApp using QTextEdit. I know that [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) only supports a small subset of HTML and CSS and I can't directly create bubbles by using HTML/CSS supported by it. Can the needed be achieved by using [QTextFrameFormat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextframeformat.html) with QTextEdit? setBackground and setBorderBrush methods looks interesting.